# How much work is done to maintain vertical position (hovering) of a drone?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, gravity, work

Ignoring all losses in the efficiency of the means to lift the drone, this would reduce down to resolving the key elements of the equation involving a) the acceleration of gravity and 2) the time, and 3) the mass. So this is really just a math problem given that we assume the acceleration of gravity to be 9.807 m/s² and the time to be 60 seconds, and the mass to be 1 Kg.
An equivalent question would be to ask: "What work is done to accelerate a mass of 1 Kg along a flat horizontal plane at a rate of 9.807 m/s² for 60 seconds?" I am not interested in the kinetic energy because it does not change in the case of the hovering drone, only the work that is done over time.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Comment: @VincentThacker This is a valid question. Even though there are specific numbers, the question is about the work done to hover, which is an interesting question. The comparison with horizontal acceleration shows the "work" done. Copy and paste doesn't make you right.

Comment: @MarkH No, this question is about specific computations which is off-topic. In addition, whether I copied and pasted this comment or not is irrelevant to its correctness.

Comment: Thank you @MarkH. This really is not a homework question. I wish to understand the math in these equations and I cannot resolve the units. I find very few discussions on any drone forums where the participants take a deep dive into the physics involved in staying in the air or moving from place to place.

Comment: @VincentThacker The units are units of one for the sake of clarity and to remove the distraction that might creep in from comments about air or volume or propellers. I used one unit of gravity, one unit of time, and one unit of mass. I saw a similar question about a helicopter and the discussion devolved into the topic of propellers. How would you re-write the general question and be certain that it does not go off on a tangent? I tried. Now it is your turn.

Answer (score 2):

Your horizontally accelerating drone is not equivalent to the hovering drone. The fact that the hovering drone is not moving means that the energy expenditure can be made arbitrarily small.

In order to stay hovering, the drone needs an upward force of $F_{drone}$. The drone hovers by pushing air down, relying on Newton's third law to have the air push the drone up. In a small amount of time $\Delta t$ the drone's propellers push a mass of air $m_{air}$ down at a certain velocity $v_{air}$ (you can feel this air moving if you place your hand underneath a hovering drone). The force felt by the air (and thus by the drone in the opposite direction) is
$$F_{air} = m_{air}a_{air} = m_{air}\frac{v_{air}}{\Delta t}$$
Or, rearranging
$$F_{air}\Delta t = m_{air}v_{air}$$
Using the third law,
$$F_{drone}\Delta t = m_{air}v_{air}$$
So, in order for a drone to hover for a certain time period ($\Delta t$), it needs to push down a certain amount of air ($m_{air}$) at a certain velocity ($v_{air}$). Notice that the drone designer can choose to push down more air at a lower velocity or less air at a higher velocity.

Now, how much power does this require? The air gains kinetic energy by the action of the propellers. In the absence of any other inefficiencies, the drone engine must supply enough power to give kinetic energy to the air. The kinetic energy that must be supplied by the drone engine in time $\Delta t$ is given by
$$K_{air} = \frac 1 2 m_{air} v_{air}^2$$
Notice that velocity is squared but mass is not. If I double the mass and halve the velocity, I get the same force with half the power. More generally, if I multiply the mass of air by $k$ and divide the velocity by $k$, then the power needed to produce the required force is reduced to $1/k$. It is more efficient to push a lot of air down slowly than to push a little air down quickly. In the ideal case, with propellers that very long and very low-density, the power needed can be reduced to arbitrarily small amounts.

It is the details of the mechanism of hovering that determine how much power is needed. For example, [here's a video of a human-powered helicopter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JN5CTugDhHw). Notice the large, slow-moving propeller blades that are designed for efficiency.

To take this to a somewhat ridiculous extreme the drone can hover with the engines off by placing the drone on a table at the desired height.

Comment: If we were to change the 'label' from drone to brick, and exclude the use of any means of support such as a table from all discussions, it would take 'work' to keep an unsupported brick in the air. The question is about 'work'. Now if we have a source of moving air attached to the floor and that source is blowing air up to support the brick, how much work is done by that source to keep the brick at a constant distance off the floor for a given period of time?

Comment: @HansenJC001 The amount of work necessary depends on the specific details of the method that makes the drone/brick/<abstract object> hover. Without these details, the work can be arbitrarily small to arbitrarily large. To take your brick example, if you replace the upward blowing air with an upward shooting laser, keeping the brick aloft will require gigawatts of power. Without a specific choice of mechanism with engineering details, it is impossible to determine the necessary work. The specific choice of mechanism determines how much work is required.

Comment: @HansenJC001 If you allow any and all means of hovering then the work required to keep the drone at the same height for a given time can be made as small as you like by having arbitrarily large slow moving rotors.  As Mark H says, unless you place some restrictions on the means of hovering (e.g. a maximum size of rotors) then the minimum power required to keep the drone at the same height is zero.

Comment: "In the ideal case, with propellers that very long and very low-density, the power needed can be reduced to arbitrarily small amounts." - At a certain point, it becomes beneficial to swap out rotary wings for linear wings, and you get an airplane.

Comment: @HansenJC001 if you put your brick on top of a magnet hovering over a superconductor then it can hover with 0 energy

Answer (score 2):

The drone must push the air (of density $\rho$) down, from beneath the rotor blades covering area $A$ - at a speed $v$, so that the change of momentum of the mass of air per second equals the weight of the drone, of mass $m$.

(this is the impulse equation, Force equals the rate of change of momentum.  From Newton's third law the upward force on the drone is equal to the downward force on the air).

The volume of air pushed down per second is $Av$ and the change in momentum of this air is $Av\rho \times v$

i.e. $$mg = Av^2\rho$$

and $$v^2 = \frac{mg}{A \rho}$$

There will be a minimum energy, per second, needed to maintain the drone stationary, equal to the kinetic energy of the air that's pushed down.

$$K.E = 0.5(Av\rho)v^2 = 0.5Av^3\rho $$
so

$$ K.E = 0.5\frac{(mg)^{3/2}}{(A \rho)^{1/2}}\tag 1$$

then we'd multiply by 60 seconds.

Taking $m=1$ $g=9.8$ $\rho = 1.3$

gives an approximate answer for the energy needed of  $$E = \frac{807}{\sqrt{A}}\tag2$$ in Joules, for the 60 seconds.  It depends on the area, taking  $A=0.1$ square meters, for example, gives about $$E=2550J$$

Comment: The mechanism is unrelated to the question. I am looking for the 'theoretical' value for the work. Could you have arrived at this value of 2550J without knowing density of the medium or the area of the propeller or the mass and velocity of the air?

Comment: @ HansenJC001 equation 1) shows what the 2550J depends on, if the drone is in air you just need the area of the propeller, and equation 2) can be used

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore all losses due to inefficiency then the work for hovering is 0.

A drone is horribly inefficient. To make things hover efficiently you can use a superconductor and a magnetic field which requires 0 energy. There are also gyro-stabilized magnets that waste very little energy hovering.

Here is a picture of a disk hovering with 0 energy

[image: Hovering with 0 energy consumption]

Comment: To keep the drone stationary you need a downward air flow and therefore there is indeed a minimum power ?

Comment: Thank you @VincentFraticelli. And now, how do I convert that power to work with the information know of the mass of the drone and the acceleration of gravity?

Comment: @HansenJC001 you specified “ignore all losses due to inefficiency” and in your comment to John Hunter you stated explicitly “The mechanism is unrelated to the question”. Under those conditions the minimum is 0, as I stated. The only way to get a non-zero number is to specify the mechanism as John Hunter did.

Comment: I had misread the details of the question. It is not possible to give an answer with your data only: it is mandatory to involve the density of the air and the surface of the propeller.

Comment: I maintain that the analogous question of accelerating a mass horizontally for a fixed unit of time  does the same work and it requires no knowledge of the medium in question nor the method used to do the acceleration.

Comment: @HansenJC001 it is not the same. You can maintain it all you like but Mother Nature disagrees

Comment: @VincentFraticelli you don't need downward flow except to maintain a pressure differential. I'm thinking free-space hovercrafts / parachutes with air pumps now.