# Energy consumption of UAV if hovering in wind conditions

Tags: energy, flow, power

I am a computer scientist unexperienced with physics, so this might be simple. I consider a UAV (drone - quadcopter) that has a task to hover, not move from the position where it was placed above the area, thus $v_x=0$ and $v_y=0$. $v_z$ should as well be $0$ so the UAV does not move up or down. If there is no wind - perfect conditions ($w=(0,0,0)$) - the expected power needed for this flight is $P$. We do not consider turbulent flows now for simplicity, only a static speed of the wind. In this scenario it is clear that if wind is non-zero from x or y direction, this will increase the power consumption. If the $w_z > 0$, thus wind flows upwards, the power should be $<P$ as this helps to keep the drone up and vice versa. We consider the drone have area of $S_z$ for z direction and $S_{xy}$ for x and y direction (both are same, the drone is symmetric).

So my question is, how to calculate the power and energy according to the wind velocity?

Comment: You could come up with some educated theoretical guess, but the best thing would be to run some tests and extrapolate data numerically. I can sketch the theory if you really want.

Comment: I don't really want the numerical results, I want the formula @FriendlyLagrangian

Comment: Right now I am checking out [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1509/1/012015/pdf), I might come with a solution myself possibly

Comment: Let me know if you need it still!

Comment: What is $w$? Is it a force, a power, a velocity...?

Comment: @Andrew velocity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further studying I found a solution in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8486942).

Knowing that propellers operate at speed $v$, we can express energy:

$$E = 1/2m_{air}*v^2$$

With $r$ being the radius of propeller, $\rho$ the density of air, 4 being number of propellers

$$m_{air} = 4 \pi r^2vt\rho$$

Knowing that

$$P = Fv = mgv$$

We can substitute as follows:

$$mgv = 2\pi r^2v^3\rho $$
Thus:
$$v = \sqrt{\frac{mg}{2\pi r^2\rho}}$$

And finally the energy is

$$E = 2\pi r^2 \rho t\sqrt{\frac{mg}{2\pi r^2\rho} - w_z}$$,

where $w_z$ is the wind speed on z axis.

Of course we need to add to this as well the wind hitting the drone from side, thus when side surface is denoted as $A$, then kinetic energy transmitted from wind to the drone during time $t$ is:

$$E_k = 1/2mv^2 = 1/2A\rho v^3t$$

In this case $v$ is the wind velocity in xy plane, because the drone is expected to have similar surface from all sides, the split calculation of x and y parts is not needed.

The same has to be done for vertical kinetic energy hitting the drone to other parts besides propellers. I am not giving one more formula as it is intuitive. The result is sum of all these energies.

Answer (score 1):

From [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/666896/how-much-work-is-done-to-maintain-vertical-position-hovering-of-a-drone/666909#666909) we have a formula for the minimum power needed to keep a drone hovering in the same position (mass of drone $m$, area of rotors $A$, air density $\rho$)

$$P = 0.5\frac{(mg)^{3/2}}{(A \rho)^{1/2}}$$

Perhaps someone could add to this to include the effect of an up or down windspeed.

Comment: $$K.E = 0.5(Av\rho)v^2 = 0.5Av^3\rho $$ - here it seems that we can adjust the $v$ according to $w_z$ from my vector. Then add formulas for x and y axes to this result. Speed $v_0$ - to hover in perfect conditions - can be count according to formula $$v^2 = \frac{mg}{A \rho}$$ and then summed with $w_z$, am I correct?